# How can Vims conceal feature be used to simplify code?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, neovim

After much Googling I have been unable to make Vim's code conceal feature work with Javascript and Typescript (without requiring a plugin).

I have been trying to use lines like the following in my `.vimrc` to conceal my code but without any luck:

```
syntax keyword Normal function conceal cchar=λ
syntax keyword Keyword return conceal cchar=>
```

Aim:

```js
// Actual
function sum(a) {
  return function inner(b) {
    return a + b
  }
}
// Displayed
λ sum a
  > inner b
    > a + b
```

Goals:

- Replace `function` with the lambda symbol
- Replace `return` with the > symbol
- Replace `[name]([args])` with `name args`
- Conceal the `{`
- Conceal the `}`

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: See `:help 'conceallevel'`.

Answer (score 1):

Your snippet appears to work as intended if you enable the "conceal" feature:

[image: cole]

See `:help 'conceallevel'`.

But you may have a kind of race condition with other syntax scripts if you don't execute those `:syntax` commands at the right time. When in a TypeScript buffer, could you do `:scriptnames` and add the output of the command to your question?

Comment: what font you are using guy?

Comment: It's [Fira Mono](https://github.com/mozilla/Fira) (not to be confused with FiraCode), specifically [this fork](https://github.com/zwaldowski/Fira/tree/zwaldowski/mod-new/otf) with added italics.